# Build ATL VS2010 project on CI server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, continuous-integration, atl

I need to build VS2010 C++ ATL project on CI server with no VS2010 installed.

The project can be successfully built on developers machine with VS2010 installed. But VS2010 cannot be installed to CI servers because that requires a license.

So, for now I'm trying the following approach:

1. Installed VS2010 Express
2. Installed Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7
3. Installed Windows Driver Kit (it includes ATL and MFC)

Although I have ATL headers and libs installed on the CI machine, I'm getting the following errors:

> error C2039: 'AtlSetPerUserRegistration' : is not a member of 'ATL'
>   error C3861: 'AtlSetPerUserRegistration': identifier not found

I compared `atlbase.h` headers from VS2010 installation and from WDK. They are different:
- `atlbase.h` from VS2010 installation does have `AtlSetPerUserRegistration` definition;
- `atlbase.h` from WDK installation does not have it.

That causes an error mentioned above.

The question is: how to configure CI build machine for building ATL projects without installing VS2010?

**Update:**
Checking `atldef.h` file I found the following:
VS2010 version has the line:

```
#define _ATL_VER 0x0A00 // Active Template Library version 10.00
```

and WDK version has the line:

```
#define _ATL_VER 0x0800 // Active Template Library version 8.00
```

So, WDK ATL version differs from the VS2010 ATL version. That's why they're not 100% compatible.

Now the question is: How to get ATL v10.0 on the build server without having VS2010 installed?

Comment: More or less current ATL is only installed with Visual Studio. WDK's ATL is compatible in just possibly basic things. You tried VS2010 Pro which is not free, so you need a commercial license for CI server. You might prefer more recent VS versions which include ATL in free (community) editions.

Comment: I need to setup more than 10 agents in TC. Setting VS2010 Pro to each of them doesn't seem to be an optimal solution. And upgrade to the newer version of VS is quite difficult, because there is a set of legacy applications with dependencies to 3rd party statically linked libraries. Thanks for your suggestion anyway )

Answer (score 1):

In case if anyone else meets the same issue, here is a workaround:

The required version of ATL is available on developers machine with VS2010 installed (e.g. VS2010 Professional).
It is located in the folder `%VCINSTALLDIR%ATLMFC`.
By default it is `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\`

Folder `ATLMFC` can be copied to the build server by hands into `%VCINSTALLDIR%`, where VS2010 Express is installed. And that makes build server able to build VS2010 ATL projects without installing VS2010.

Though this is a workaround. And I'd like to see  better solution if any. So, I'm not accepting my answer.